# how to navigate or show other view controller when indexPath cell pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

i have one collection view with `2 cells`. So by default first cell will be `0,1......` And i also have `2 viewcontroller`. Named `1. firstVC, 2. secondVC`. What i need is, when i tap cell 1 it should show the `firstVC` as a `modal` view `segue`.

same like when i press second cell, it should show the `secondVC` as a `modal` view  `segue`..

How to do that, here i can print which cell i am selecting. How to show that viewcontrollers ??

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // You can use indexPath to get "cell number x", or get the cell like:
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if((indexPath.row) == 0) {
        print("Layout 1 clicked")

    }
    else if((indexPath.row) == 1) {
        print("Layout 2 clicked")
    }
    else if((indexPath.row) == 2) {
        print("Layout 3 clicked")
    }
    else if((indexPath.row) == 3) {
        print("Layout 4 clicked")
    }


    }
```

please help me out...Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.presentViewController(UIViewController, animated: Bool)` or add segue in the Interface Builder and call it using `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(String, sender: AnyObject?)`. 
Also when adding segue in the IB make sure to change it to "present modally" if you need to.